# If $f( \cos^2(x) ) = \cos^2(x)$ can I assume that $f(x) = x$?

Tags: functions

I am new to functions and domains and I am not sure that I can assume following because I think that the range of first function is $[0, 1]$ and the range of second is $(-\infty, \infty)$.

The original question: Find $f(x)$ if $f( \cos^2(x) ) = \cos^2(x)$

Comment: That is a totally bizarre question.  Are you sure you haven't omitted anything?

Comment: Check composition of functions.

Comment: Since  the range of $\cos^2x $ is $[0,1]$, for any $ t $ in this range we indeed have that $ f (t)=t $. However, for values of $ t $ less than $0$ or bigger than $1$, we have no information about $ f $. That is to say that *any* $ f $ whose restriction to $[0,1] $ is the identity satisfies the given equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. All you can deduce is that
$f(x) = x$ for
$0 \le x \le 1$,
since that is the range of values
that $\cos^2(x)$ takes on.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assume that, unless you know more about the function. For example, perhaps $f(x)=\operatorname{min}(x, 1)$.